# Help identifying LEGO set, smaller pieces with M printed on them?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

These are smaller LEGO's than my kids normally play with. Some have an "M" on it and some still have "LEGO" on them.  What sets could these be from?

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 5):

http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Modulex From the sounds of it looks like they are part of the Modulex line that was released for professionals. From what I've read they are smaller than normal LEGO system parts.

Comment: With those "M" logos on the studs I was sure this was a clone brand.  It was neat to learn about Modulex's association with LEGO.